# Programmatically add table cells to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can't seem to find the method/line of code that I can use to add cells to a table in xcode without Storyboard (if that's possible). It seems like a really quick solution exists I just haven't found it.
If you know an example of this, please point it out.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SubViewController.h"
#import "SubTableViewController.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //subviewcontroller = tabbarcontroller

    UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    SubViewController * firstTab= [[SubViewController alloc] init ];
    [firstTab.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    firstTab.title = @"first";

    UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

    SubViewController *secondTab = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    [secondTab.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    secondTab.title = @"second";
    UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondTab];

    SubTableViewController * table = [[SubTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:table];

    table.title = @"third";

    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,navigationController2, nav3];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The code goes in your custom table view controller class where you implement the various `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tableViewController template provided by xcode there is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

- for sections in tableView

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

number of rows in each section

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

where you can set text of each cell

I'ld rather suggest you should check out some basic tutorials [appcode tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/)

Answer (score 0):

PLease try writing following code in

--(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
return cell;
```

And you can add your custom views to above code